# как правильно освобождать динамическую память в си?

Tags: c, malloc, free

недавно начал программировать на си и хотел узнать, есть ли разница в каком порядке очищать динамически выделенную память?
допустим есть такой код(если не заморачиваться)

```
char *a = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
char *b = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
char *c = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));

//1 случай
free(a)
free(c)
free(b)

//2 случай
free(c)
free(b)
free(a)
```

есть ли разница между первым и вторым случаем?

Comment: Разницы нет. Главное не забыть освободить захваченное, и не освободить одно дважды.

Comment: ...и не пытаться использовать освобождённую память после собственно освобождения

Comment: Освобождать лучше в порядке, обратном порядку аллкирования - фрагментация будет меньше. Но это такие тонкости, которые Вам пока не нужны.

Comment: Мысли в слух: если бы порядок был бы так важен, в C++ при освобождении вектора элементы бы удалялись с конца к началу. Но нет, они удаляются с начала к концу. Лично мне как программисту удобнее писать освобождение ресурсов в порядке обратном их распределению. Но это просто предпочтение, никакой рациональной основы под этим нет.

Comment: @andreymal а почему нельзя использовать освобожденную память повторно?

Comment: @yaya потому что после освобождения память уже не принадлежит вам и может переиспользоваться для других нужд. Если вы попытаетесь использовать освобождённую память, то в лучшем случае операционная система просто скажет «куда ты лезешь блин?» и убьёт программу, а в худшем случае (если память начала переиспользоваться для чего-то ещё) вы случайно измените произвольный участок своей программы с непредсказуемыми и возможно разрушительными последствиями

Comment: @andreymal понял, спс

Comment: Порядок не важен. Но очень желательно выполнять очистку памяти в конце функции, за барьером памяти asm volatile("":::"memory"); - гарантия защиты от слишком умного компилятора.